# displaying existing html pages (one at a time) in tool

Tags: javascript, html

I am building a tool in which I am trying to open a html file having single column or multiple column. I want to get each section of html file to be displayed in the display section of my tool as we do so in the browser.My javascript code for display page is:

```
function open(htmlFile) {
  var htmlFile1 = htmlFile;
  alert(htmlFile1);
  var parser = new DOMParser();
  var doc = parser.parseFromString(htmlFile, "text/html");
  var all = doc.getElementsByTagName("body");
  var sections = doc.getElementsByClassName("section");
  alert(sections);
}
```

Comment: So, what's the question here?

Comment: Sounds like you want [Iframes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)?

Comment: May be you want to get all **section** in the HTML page?

Comment: yes I want to get all section.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to get all `section` of your HTML page.If there is no `custom class` or `ID` on it then you have to get by **getElementsByTagName("section")**.

Below is the code snippet may help you:

```js
var htmlFile="<html><body><p>Hello World!</p><p>We're here</p><section><h1>WWF</h1><p>The World Wide Fund for Nature (WWF) is....</p></section></body></html>";


function open(htmlFile) {
  var htmlFile1 = htmlFile;
  alert(htmlFile1);
  var parser = new DOMParser();
  var doc = parser.parseFromString(htmlFile, "text/html");
  var all = doc.getElementsByTagName("body");
  var sections = doc.getElementsByTagName("section");
  $.each(sections, function() { 
   alert(this.innerHTML);
});
}
open(htmlFile);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```